# Solve this PDE $u_x+u_y+2u_z=0$,$u(1,y,z)=yz$ (problem with initial conditions/particular solution)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential, characteristics

Find the particular solution of the part differential equation $u_x+u_y+2u_z=0$ that satisfies the data $u(1,y,z)=yz$

So:

$\frac {dx}{1}=\frac {dy}{1} = \frac{dz}{2}$

$\int dx=\int dy \Rightarrow x=y+C_1 \Rightarrow C_1=x-y$

$2\int dx=\int dz \Rightarrow 2x=z+C_2 \Rightarrow C_2=2x-z$

General solution: $u(x,y,z)=F(x-y,2x-z)$

I use a initial condition: $yz=F(1-y,2-z) \Rightarrow $
Now, I don't know what to do next?

How can I get particular solution for this condition?

---

PS: We only did this example in class earlier:
$\\ u(x,y)=F(2x-3y),u(0,y)=81y^{4}$
$81y^{4}=F(2*0-3y) \Rightarrow 81y^{4}=F(-3y) \Rightarrow t=-3y \Rightarrow F(t)=t^{4} \Rightarrow u=(2x-3y)^{4}$

I try use wolfram alpha, which can give general solution with this prompt `D[u[x,y,z],x]+D[u[x,y,z],y]+2*D[u[x,y,z],z]=0`, but when I write this prompt `D[u[x,y,z],x]+D[u[x,y,z],y]+2*D[u[x,y,z],z]=0,u(1,y,z)=y*z`, doesn't return a particular solution, there is another way to do it (with wolfram)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $y'=1-y,z'=2-z$. Now rewrite $F(1-y,2-z)=yz$ in terms of $y',z'$.

Comment: I'm still don't know what to do next $F(y',z')=(1-y')(2-z') \Rightarrow F(y',z')=2-z'-2y'+z'y'$

Comment: Right. So now you know what function $F$ is, and therefore can express $u(x,y,z)=F(x-y,2x-z)$ in terms of $x,y,z$.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind, is that now: $z'=x-y,y'=2x-z$, so: $$u(x,y,z)=2-2x+z-2x+2y+(2x-z)*(x-y) \Rightarrow u(x,y,z)=2-4x+2y+z-2xy-zx+yz+2x^2$$ this is correct?

Comment: If you think you have a solution, plug it into the PDE and check. That said, it's helpful to leave $F$ as $F(y',z')=(1-y')(2-z')\implies F(y,z)=(1-y)(2-z)$. (The primes are just labels at this point: if you know what $F$ does to $(y',z')$, you know what it does to $(y,z)$.) Then $u(x,y,z)=F(x-y,2x-z)=(1-x+y)(2-2x+z)$ which is a more compact version of what you wrote.

Comment: You mean check PDE like this?  $$u(1,y,z)=2-4+2y+z-2y-z+yz+2=yz$$, so yes it's correct ;) 

I have question: Is it possible to use wolfram alpha or another computer program for this, or is it impossible with the initial condition?

Comment: Not that I know of: the best I know is to use Wolfram Alpha to get the general solution, then use the above technique to infer $F$ and thus $u$.

Comment: I have one more PDE task (and problem with general solution): (I would like to open a chat with you, but I don't have enough reputation) so maybe I create new question and send you link

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. The characteristic curves satisfy the equations
$$
\dot{x}=1,\qquad\dot{y}=1,\qquad\dot{z}=2,\qquad\dot{u}=0, \tag{1}
$$
which have as general solution
\begin{align}
x&=x_0+t, \tag{2} \\
y&=y_0+t, \tag{3} \\
z&=z_0+2t, \tag{4}\\
u&=u_0. \tag{5}
\end{align}
The particular solution $u(1,y,z)=yz$ corresponds to the initial conditions $x_0=1$ and $u_0=y_0z_0$. The latter condition and Eqs. $(3)$-$(5)$ imply
$u=(y-t)(z-2t)$; the former and Eq. $(2)$ imply $t=x-1$. Combining these results we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y,z)=(y-x+1)(z-2x+2). \tag{6}
$$

Comment: Can you answer me what if:
$$
\dot{x}=x,\qquad\dot{y}=y,\qquad\dot{z}=xy,\qquad\dot{u}=0,u(x,y,0)=x^{2}+y^{2} \tag{1}
$$
If:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}=x \Rightarrow \int \frac{dx}{x}=\int(dt) \Rightarrow x&=e^{t}+x_0, \tag{2} \\
y&=e^{t}+y_0, \tag{3} \\
\frac{dz}{dt}=xy \Rightarrow z=? \tag{4}\\
u&=u_0. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

Can you solve this method this PDE and write particular solution for your method?